# %Change in Oil Price

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to plot %change in Oil price over the years 1988 to 2022 as per below code:

```
change_in_oil_price <- read.csv("Desktop/R models/change in oil price.csv")
head(change_in_oil_price)

plot1 <- ggplot(change_in_oil_price, aes(Year, Annual...Change, group = 1)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
labs(x = "Year", y = "%change in Price",
title = "Annual Change in Brent Crude Price")
plot1
```

However, I am not getting the Y-axis as desired. I want 0 in the middle so I can compare/analyze the prices. Please see the attached Image.

[image]

I am trying to fix the y-axis.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: .. this said: The issue is that your `Annual...Change` column isn't a numeric. To fix your issue convert it to a numeric using e.g. `readr::parse_number(Annual...Change)`.

Comment: @stefan thanks for your comment, here's what the data looks like:Year Average.Closing.Price Year.Open Year.High Year.Low Year.Close Annual...Change
1 2022                $97.06    $78.25   $133.18   $78.25    $110.39          42.92%
2 2021                $70.86    $50.37    $85.76   $50.37     $77.24          50.80%
3 2020                $41.96    $67.05    $70.25    $9.12     $51.22         -24.42%
4 2019                $64.28    $54.06    $74.94   $53.23     $67.77          34.01%

Comment: Annual...Change is a % number, I did as you mentioned but still the problem persists: change_in_oil_price <- read.csv("Desktop/R models/change in oil price.csv")
head(change_in_oil_price)

readr::parse_number(change_in_oil_price$Annual...Change)

plot1 <- ggplot(chasx``nge_in_oil_price, aes(Year, Annual...Change, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "%change in Price", 
       title = "Annual Change in Brent Crude Price")
plot1

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the issue is that your `Annual...Change` column isn't a numeric but a character. For humans it's a percentage number but for R it's a character string made up of digits, a dot and a percent symbol.

To fix your issue convert your `Annual...Change` column to a numeric which could e.g. easily be done with `readr::parse_number` which will take care of the percent symbol.

Using some fake example data to mimic your real data:

```
# Create example data
change_in_oil_price <- data.frame(
  Year = 1990:2020,
  Annual...Change = paste0(seq(-70, 150, length.out = 31), "%")
)
```

Without converting to a numeric I run in the same issue as you, i.e. the numbers on the y axis get ordered alphabetically:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

ggplot(change_in_oil_price, aes(Year, Annual...Change, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "%change in Price",
       title = "Annual Change in Brent Crude Price")
```

[image]

Converting to a numeric gives a nice plot instead with the numbers in the desired order. Additionally I make use of `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(scale = 1))` to format the axis labels as percentages:

```r
change_in_oil_price$Annual...Change <- readr::parse_number(change_in_oil_price$Annual...Change )

ggplot(change_in_oil_price, aes(Year, Annual...Change, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(scale = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "%change in Price",
       title = "Annual Change in Brent Crude Price")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, it's clear now bro. Really, thanks a lot for your swift reply.